# GitLab "Merged Result" Pipeline - Does it change all existing pipelines?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, merge-request

I've found the (a?) documentation page for these:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html

And I've found the check-box in the settings:

[image]

But I'm not clear on whether this setting will:

- enable a feature that we can reference in the yaml config file, and use it to create *additional* pipelines that run on an MR, **as well** as retaining our existing pipelines that run targetting the actual commit that's been pushed?

or

- change all of the existing CI pipelines to now run on the merged result, **instead** of the direct commit.

If it's the former ... then how do I actually create such a pipeline - I can't see anything about how to configure these in the yaml file?

Comment: Enabling merged results pipelines just adds an additional pipeline. You still get the normal `detached` MR pipeline as well as branch pipelines, as long as your pipeline jobs are configured for that. You can use `rules:` based on `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE` to control which types of MR pipelines you want to run. But in either case, the setting will only apply to new pipelines/MR events.

Comment: @sytech I tested it, and it seems a lot like it *replaced* the existing pipeline. Enabling the checkbox and then pushing branches with an unchanged YAML config has resulted in the MR UI showing "Merged result pipeline #xxxxxxxxx running", but no "Merge request pipeline #xxxxxxxx running", as it used to.

Comment: The hash cited on it, is a non-existent hash (in the remote repo)

Comment: And *all* the checks are now behaving as though they're being run on a merge commit.

Comment: When I add `  rules:    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE != 'merged_result'` to a check, then that check doesn't appear to be run at all.

Comment: Interesting! There _should_ at least be a branch pipeline in addition to the merged result pipeline, unless there's some other job rule or workflow rule preventing it. However, it is expected that only one pipeline will be associated with the MR and shown in the merge request UI. Be sure to check the pipelines page for the running pipelines.

Comment: Nope :( during the period I had the check box enabled, every entry in the pipelines view was tagged with `merged result` and none with `merge request` :(